# Index Match & Filter Function

Tags: excel

EDIT:
@all I suppose I asked the question poorly... Perhaps this is a better way of asking..

```
=FILTER($D$13:$V$5000,(($F$13:$F$5000=$X$6)+($F$13:$F$5000=$Y$6))*($T$13:$T$5000>=$X$5)*($T$13:$T$5000<=$Y$5)*(D5=$D$13:$D5000))
```

The above gives me a filtered universe based on an existing dataset. Is it possible for me to find the row in which a particular cell is closest to a referenced number? I am filtering down a universe of corporate bonds and trying to find the most liquid bond.

ORIGINAL:
I am trying to run an index match formula where I filter down an existing dataset, and then find the row in which the nth column is closest to a referenced number.

I can do these separately, i.e. create a filtered down dataset and then run an `index,match(min(abs` etc on the filtered data.

Instead I am trying to accomplish both tasks in one function. Any help here?

`INDEX(FILTER($D$13:$U$5000,(($F$13:$F$5000=$X$6)+($F$13:$F$5000=$Y$6))*($T$13:$T$5000>=$X$5)*($T$13:$T$5000<=$Y$5)*(D5=$D$13:$D5000)),MATCH(MIN(ABS(AQ12:AQ18-G5)),ABS(AQ12:AQ18-G5),0))`

Comment: So you want the closest number? why then put 0 as the final argument in match? That drives an exact match - use 1 or -1 based on less or greater.

Comment: What is the correlation between `$D$13:$U$5000` and `AQ12:AQ18` one is 4988 rows and the other is 7 rows.  How can finding a match in 7 rows correlate to the larger, will the larger always filter to 7 rows?

Comment: Your current formula requires further explanation. As it stands, it makes no sense: first, you're filtering a range of 4988 cells, which you're then INDEXing by passing a row parameter which could only ever be a number from 1 to 7?

Comment: @all I suppose I asked the question poorly... Perhaps this is a better way of asking..

=FILTER($D$13:$V$5000,(($F$13:$F$5000=$X$6)+($F$13:$F$5000=$Y$6))*($T$13:$T$5000>=$X$5)*($T$13:$T$5000<=$Y$5)*(D5=$D$13:$D5000))



The above gives me a filtered universe based on an existing dataset. Is it possible for me to find the row in which a particular cell is closest to a referenced number? I am filtering down a universe of corporate bonds and trying to find the most liquid bond.

Comment: @Cole please [edit] the post with clarifications.  Do not put clarifications in the comments

Comment: So test each part, match takes 3 values to control how it matches (1, 0, -1) so test to see what works for your data. As you don't show example data we cannot guess.

Comment: Which column in the filtered data holds the numbers to be compared?

Comment: @ScottCraner it would be the last column, which is column 19.

Comment: @ScottCraner by column 19 i mean column V

Comment: @ScottCraner I saw your post about utilizing the LET function.. i do think this is putting me on the right track but i'm still having trouble referencing a column set in the filtered dataset. I'll keep working through it and let you know if i find a solution, although as i'm sure you can tell im admittedly an amateur at best

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.